# How to resize webview according to screen resolution in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, storyboard

I am using storyboards. I am unable to resize webview according to the screen size in my storyboard.

[image: iphone5 and iphone4 resolutions]

I want header to be of same size for both resolution but change the height of webview according to screen resolution.

I can't use Autolayout because I want to deploy my app for ios5 and above.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set Your `Webview` frame according to `UIScreen` like Bellow where you alloc your `` `webview ``

```
CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
webFrame.origin.y -= 20.0; // statusbar 20 px cut from y of frame
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **.m** file under `viewDidLoad` add this code.

```
webview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.he‌​ight);
```

Add a referencing outlet of your web view to webView and then that should set the webView height to your view height.

Explanation: The view will get longer when you deploy to a 4 inch simulator causing the webView to change to the view's size.